# Phoenix | redirect to current path in html

Tags: phoenix-framework

In my header page `app.html.eex` I have this link:

```
<a href="<%= Routes.page_path(@conn, :index, locale: "en") %>"><%= gettext "English" %></a>
```

If a user is on any other path other than the root `/` , the user will be redirected to the root path, obviously because I send them there with `... Routes.page_path(@conn, :index ...` .

*So how can I form a link where it sends the user to the page he is on* ***but*** with the parameter `locale: "en"` as I am processing this parameter in a browser plug and setting it as a language cookie and then return the user to the page the user was on.

Something like this:

```
<%= Routes.go(@conn.current_path, locale:"en")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know to make this happen requires you write the query string yourself (instead of passing a map, which is nicer). It looks like this:

```
<a href="<%= Routes.path(@conn, "#{@conn.request_path}?locale=en") %>"><%= gettext "English" %></a>
```

This link will take you to the same page but you will only have the `locale=en` query params (any other ones will be gone). That, is you will only have `%{"locale" => "en"}` for your `@conn.query_params`.

If you want to investigate further yourself, you should try to understand the source code for the router helpers. It lives in `$PROJECT/deps/phoenix/lib/phoenix/router/helpers.ex`. I find this code very hard to understand. The `unquote` magic is new to me.